# Need to MATCH instead of MERGE

Tags: twitter, neo4j, cypher

My Neo4j instance is populated with a complete Alumni data set from a local University. A small % (15K) of the (248K) nodes (n:Alumni) include a twitter user_name. My goal is to use a GITHUB app (TWIITER to NEO4J) that loads and links twitter screenNames in order to obtain relationship data. My issue is that the query below (which is contain in the java script from the GITHUB app) Cypher creates unwanted Follower/Following nodes that do not match the Alumni screen_name.  I would like to write a query that only allows relationship to be created from the app. Let me know if this is clearer....

```
MERGE (targetNode:Person {screen_name: {screenName}})
FOREACH (friend in {userList} |
MERGE (friendNode:Person {screen_name: friend.screen_name})
ON CREATE SET friendNode=friend
MERGE (targetNode)-[:FOLLOWS]->(friendNode))
```

This was my idea - I set the MERGE to MATCH Alumni

```
MATCH (targetNode:Alumni {screen_name: {screenName}})
WHERE targetNode:Alumni.screen_name = {screen_name} 
FOREACH (friend in {userList} |
MATCH (friendNode:Alumni {screen_name: friend.screen_name})
SET friendNode=friend
MERGE (targetNode)-[:FOLLOWS]->(friendNode))
```

Thanks for any thoughts...

```
var multiline = require('multiline');

exports.upsertOne = multiline(function(){/*
  MERGE (n:Person {screen_name: {screenName}})
  ON CREATE SET n+={userMap}
  RETURN n
*/});

/*
 * Parameters are:
 *
 * screenName - string, the handle of the person to attach followers to
 * userList - array of objects, people to merge and create relationships
 */
exports.upsertManyAndFollows = multiline(function() {/*
  MATCH (followeeNode:Alumni {screen_name: {screenName}}) 
  UNWIND {userList} as follower 
    MATCH (followerNode:Alumni {screen_name: follower.screen_name})
    SET followerNode=follower
    MERGE (followerNode)-[:FOLLOWS]->(followeeNode)
*/});


/*
 * Parameters are:
 *
 * screenName - string, the handle of the person to attach followers to
 * userList - array of objects, people to merge and create relationships
 */
exports.upsertManyAndFriends = multiline(function() {/*
  MATCH (targetNode:Person {screen_name: {screenName}})
  UNWIND {userList} as friend
    MATCH (friendNode:Person {screen_name: friend.screen_name})
    SET friendNode=friend
    MERGE (targetNode)-[:FOLLOWS]->(friendNode)
*/});

/*
 * Parameters are:
 *
 * screenName - string, the handle of the person that is at the center of the graph.
 * 
 */
```

Comment: You haven't made clear what problem you're encountering and where exactly you need help. Please clarify your description before this gets closed.

Comment: One thing to note, though...you said you created :Person nodes in another part of the app, but you're using :Alumni nodes in the last query. Make sure you're using the same labels.

Comment: please let me know if this helps - it not I'll try again...

Comment: That helps a bit, but I'm still a bit confused. You're using MATCH instead of MERGE in your query, and now the only MERGE is for the :FOLLOWS relationship. This shouldn't be creating any new nodes. Also, you've mentioned a user_name property on :Alumni nodes, but this isn't present anywhere in your query.

Comment: it doesn't work - the WHERE statement give a syntax error.

Comment: screenName - i the worlds worst writer....

Comment: You actually don't need that WHERE clause at all, you're already matching on an alumni with the screen name. You can remove that line entirely. And yes, make sure the parameter names passed in match with the parameters used in the query. You have both `{screenName}` and `{screen_name}` in there, one of those is probably wrong.

Comment: its only "screen_name" on the pass - the app uses screenName as a javascript call for data - akin to a (line.screenName) in a LOAD CSV

Comment: MATCH and FOREACH gave a error

Comment: Thats why I added the WHERE - I will edit - Sorry for the spam - I'm a newbie

Comment: You can edit comments for up to 5 minutes. Please do that instead of spamming with new comments.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this instead, though make sure you use the correct screen name (you have both `{screenName}` and `{screen_name}` in your query, so one of these is wrong).

Provided your :Alumni nodes are already created, this should work.

```
MATCH (targetNode:Alumni {screen_name: {screenName}})
UNWIND {userList} as friend
MATCH (friendNode:Alumni {screen_name: friend.screen_name})
SET friendNode=friend
MERGE (targetNode)-[:FOLLOWS]->(friendNode)
```

Comment: exports.upsertOne = multiline(function(){/*
  MATCH (n:Alumni {screen_name: {screenName}})
  SET n={userMap}
  RETURN n

Do you think the above query will overwrite my Alumni Nodes current property? Sorry for the spam!!!  Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, setting a node with a map `SET n = {userMap}` replaces all properties on the node with the properties in the userMap. If you want to only overwrite and add properties from the map, and keep all other properties on the node that aren't overwritten, use the `+=` operator.

Comment: It's not working - Giving me a split syntax error
c:\Users\jim.morgan\Documents\Twitter_API_4_neo4j>node app
TypeError: (e.message || "").split is not a function
    at formatStack (c:\Users\jim.morgan\Documents\Twitter_API_4_neo4j\node_modul
es\neo4j\lib\GraphDatabase.js:2:7311)
    at Error.stack

Comment: That's not enough information to troubleshoot. Can you edit your description to include the entire query, and determine which line that error is occurring and point that out? Given that we don't have access to your js file, the line number of the error is useless to us.